# Is registered atexit handler inherited by spawned child processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, atexit

I am writing a daemon program using python 2.5.  In the main process an exit handler is registered with `atexit` module, it **seems** that the handler gets called  when each child process ends, which is not I expected.

I noticed this behavior isn't mentioned in python `atexit` doc, anybody knows the issue? If this is how it should behave, how can I unregister the exit handler in children processes? There is a atexit.unregister in version 3.0, but I am using 2.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an API to do it in Python 2.5, but you can just:

```
import atexit
atexit._exithandlers = []
```

in your child processes - if you know you only have one exit handler installed, and that no other handlers are installed. However, be aware that some parts of the stdlib (e.g. `logging`) register `atexit` handlers. To avoid trampling on them, you could try:

```
my_handler_entries = [e for e in atexit._exithandlers if e[0] == my_handler_func]
for e in my_handler_entries:
    atexit._exithandlers.remove(e)
```

where `my_handler_func` is the `atexit` handler you registered, and this should remove your entry without removing the others.

Comment: +1: Better solution than mine, since we really get access to _exithandlers. Forgot that __all__ is only used when "from atexit import *".

Answer (score 4):

When you `fork` to make a child process, that child is an exact copy of the parent -- including of course registered exit functions as well as all other code and data structures. I believe that's the issue you're observing -- of course it's not mentioned in each and every module, because it necessarily applies to every single one.

Comment: Absolutely, I tend to forget basic CS facts in practice, thank you for reminding of this.

Comment: Note that this is no longer true in recent versions of Python. The registered `atexit` functions are not called by forked processes. See https://bugs.python.org/issue39675

Answer (score 1):

`atexit.register()` basically registers your function in `atexit._exithandlers`, which is a module private list of functions called by `sys.exitfunc()`. You can set `exitfunc()` to your custom made exit handler function, which then checks for child status or simply unregisters it. What about just copying the 3.0 `atexit.py` to your local source tree and using that instead?

EDIT: I copied the atexit.py from my 2.6 version and extended it by

```
def unregister(func, *targs, **kargs):
    _exithandlers.remove((func, targs, kargs))
```

If you take that instead of your original version it should work. I have not tested it with subprocesses, though.

Comment: There is no atext.py in 3.0, atexit module in 3.0 is written in C.

Comment: Right, but you can also take atexit.py from the 2.x versions